# A smooth bump function with Neumann boundary condition

Tags: real-analysis

Let $d \ge 2$ be a positive integer. Let $\Phi\colon \mathbb{R}^{d-1} \to \mathbb{R}$ is $C^3$-function with $\Phi(0)=0.$ We define a unbounded domain $D \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ by
\begin{align*}
D=\{x=(x_1,\ldots,x_{d-1},x_d) \in \mathbb{R}^d\mid x_d>\Phi(x_1,\ldots,x_{d-1})\}.
\end{align*}

Let $a \in \overline{D}$ and $r \in (0,1]$ such that $B(a,r) \cap \partial D\neq \emptyset.$ Here, $B(a,r)$ denotes a open ball centered at $a$ with radius $r$.

I am looking for a function $f\colon \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ with the following property:

1. $f$ is nonnegative and $0< f \le 1$ on $D \cap B(a,r)$,
2. $f$ is compactly supported and smooth (more precisely, $f \in C^3(\overline{ D})$),
3. $f$ satisfies the Neumann boundary. That is, for any $x \in \partial D$, we have
   $
   \langle \nabla f(x),\nu(x) \rangle=0.
   $ Here, $\nu(x)$ denotes the inward unit normal vector at $x \in \partial D.$

**Can we construct  such a function $f$?**

If $D$ is the half space, I can construct such a  function. Indeed, we take a smooth function $g\colon \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $g=1$ on $B(a,r)$ and $g=0$ outside $B(a,2r)$. For $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_{d-1},x_d)$, we let $\hat{x}=(x_1,\ldots,x_{d-1},-x_d)$. Then,
\begin{align*}
f(x)=\{g(x)+g(\hat{x})\}/2, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}^d
\end{align*}
satisfies the  all requirements.

Comment: Have you tried defining it locally by transferring your problem to the problem on half space? Once you have done this (if you can), then use partitions of unity to patch up all your local computations and get a global one.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh Thank you for your comment. I don't quite understand the method you proposed.  We write the function for transportation as $\phi\colon  \mathbb{H}^d \to D$ ($\mathbb{H}^d$ is the $d$-dimensional upper half space). Then, can we show that $f\circ \phi^{-1}$ satisfies the Neumann boundary condition on $\partial D$ ? Here, $f$ is a smooth function satisfying the all conditions when $D=\mathbb{H}^d$.

Comment: In order to get that, we have to construct our $\phi$ carefully. I have not worked the details out, but I do think that such a construction is possible.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh Thank you. I'm wondering how to get such a function $ \ \phi$.

Comment: About the main question, the smooth part is a redundancy since a bump function must be smooth by definition: bump function $\in C_c^{\infty}$... this requirement makes that at the boundaries all its derivatives must be zero since is matching the zero constant outside its definied domain and need to preserve smoothness $\lim\limits_{x \to \partial D^{\pm}} \frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x)=0\,\forall n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$, which must be added to the Boundaries conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the difficult component of this problem is interpreting the 3rd condition $\vec\nabla f \cdot\vec\nu=0$ visually as the requirement of $f(\vec{y})$ for $y\in\mathbb{R}^d$ to be increasing only in the direction normal to $\vec\nu$, hence tangent to the surface defined by $\Phi(\vec x)$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}^{d-1}$

We can do this very simply by defining a cylindrical frame that varies with $\vec y$ such that $\vec \nu$ defines the polar/vertical direction. We see that the tangent plane for $\Phi$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ is actually the $\mathbb{R}^{d-1}$ subspace defined by:
$$\vec\rho_x=\left(\frac{\vec\nabla_x\Phi}{\|\vec\nabla_x\Phi\|},\|\vec\nabla_x\Phi\|\right)$$

where $\vec\nabla$ is the usual gradient operator on Euclidean space. When normalized, this frame becomes

$$\hat\rho_x=\frac{1}{\|\vec\nabla\Phi\|\sqrt{1+\|\vec\nabla\Phi\|^2}}\;\left(\vec\nabla\Phi,\,\|\vec\nabla\Phi\|^2\right)$$
$$\hat z_x=\vec\nu(x)$$

Technically, this is not a full frame, since we would need another set of $d-2$ vectors that are orthonormal with both $\hat\rho$ and $\hat\nu$. However this does not prevent us from writing the usual test function, normalized by the maximum diameter of the ball, on $\mathbb{R}^d$ that merely depends on $\rho$ and not the other $d-2$ directions:

$$f_x(y)=\exp\left(-\frac{1}{1-(\rho_x/2)^2}\right)$$

where the covector $\rho_x$ is dual to $\hat\rho_x$ such that $\rho_x(\hat\rho_x)=1$ and $\rho_x(\hat z_x)=0$

Comment: Unfortunately, this is only a local definition of $f(x)$ so that we will have to define a collection of such functions to cover each point in $\bar{D}$ with suitably continuous maps between them.